# Saving and reading files on Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hi I'm creating a "Toilet paper tracker" on ***visual basic*** and I'm struggling with **saving and reading files**, I know I am missing stuff. The user should be able to login and input a threshold and when reached a warning will pop up saying "buy more toilet paper" *(i haven't coded this yet)* and the user can add to create a total and subtract from it too. The user should also be able to save the total to a file and I want the program to be able to read the file and change the total if the user wants to add or subtract again. It would be greatly appreciated if you pointed me in the right direction, I'm only young so it's relatively simple. **Here is my program :)**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmTPT
    Private Sub TPT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call loadchangetotal()

    End Sub
    Sub loadchangetotal()
        cboChange.Items.Add("Add to Total")
        cboChange.Items.Add("Subtract from Total")

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboVenue_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboChange.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboChange.Text = "Add to Total" Then
            Dim frmChangeACopy As New frmChangeA

            frmChangeACopy.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        ElseIf cboChange.Text = "Subtract from Total" Then
            Dim frmChangeSCopy As New frmChangeS

            frmChangeSCopy.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReturn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim frmLoginCopy As New frmLogin

        frmLoginCopy.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtThreshold.Text = ""
        cboChange.Text = ""
        txtTotal.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub LogoutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim frmLoginCopy As New frmLogin

        frmLoginCopy.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
 Private Sub btnReadTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReadTotal.Click
        Dim FileReader As StreamReader
        Dim result As DialogResult
        result = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog
        If result = DialogResult.OK Then
            FileReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.Filename)
            txtFileContent.Text = FileReader.ReadToEnd()           'i want to be able to read a 
                                                                   'previously saved total so that
            FileReader.Close()                                     'it can be used to find the new total 
                                                                   'after it has been added to
        End If                                                     'or subtratced 
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Call SaveFile()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        Dim A, S, NewTotal As Integer

        A = Val(frmChangeA.txtAdd.Text)

        S = Val(frmChangeS.txtSubtract.Text)

        NewTotal = A - S 'I want to be able to load a previously saved total if one exists and add and 
                                       'subtract from it


    End Sub
End Class

Sub SaveFile()
    Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim results As DialogResult
    results = SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog
    If results = DialogResult.OK Then
        FileWriter = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, False)
        FileWriter.Write(txtFileContent.Text)                         ' is txtFileContent supposed to be 
                                                                         '   the name of my textbox?
        FileWriter.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Design

[image: img_design]

Comment: Your description is far too vague. SO is for SPECIFIC problems. What SPECIFIC thing are you trying to achieve and EXACTLY what happens that you don't expect or doesn't happen that you do expect. You need to be able to point to exactly where in the code it behaves unexpectedly and what the expected and actual behaviour are.

Comment: Like @jmcilhinney said you need to detail what exactly is going wrong. Basically that means to debug your code and step thru line by line and compare the actual result with your exepcted. If there are any errors/expcetions try to understand them and if you don´t, come back and ask.

Comment: You could just define and use an Integer in your [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019) instead of writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The key point of this problem lies in reading and writing data from text. It is a clear idea to write two methods to achieve `read` and `write`.

You can refer to the following code. The two methods in the following example are `WriteTotal()`,  `ReadTotal()`.

Design:

[image: Design]

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Oldtotal As Integer
Dim Newtotal As Integer
Private Sub btnLoadTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadTotal.Click
    WriteTotal()
    ReadTotal()
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateTotal.Click      
    cboChange.Text = Nothing
    WriteTotal()
    ReadTotal()
    MsgBox("Inventory updated")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cboChange.SelectedIndex = 0
    ReadTotal()
End Sub

Sub WriteTotal()      
    Using swriter As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("D:/paperstore.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        If cboChange.Text = "Add to Total" Then
            Newtotal = Oldtotal + CType(txtThreshold.Text, Integer)
            swriter.WriteLine(Newtotal)

        ElseIf cboChange.Text = "Subtract from Total" Then
            If CType(txtThreshold.Text, Integer) > Oldtotal Then
                swriter.WriteLine(Oldtotal)
                MsgBox("buy more toilet paper")
            Else
                Newtotal = Oldtotal - CType(txtThreshold.Text, Integer)
                swriter.WriteLine(Newtotal)
            End If
        Else
            swriter.WriteLine(txtTotal.Text)
        End If
    End Using       
End Sub

Sub ReadTotal()
    Using sreader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("D:/paperstore.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
          Try
            Oldtotal = sreader.ReadLine()
            txtTotal.Text = Oldtotal
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End
        End Try
    End Using       
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: From the docs "This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If you have further questions, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Don't Catch and Throw. You could just use a [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement#:~:text=Sometimes%20your%20code%20requires%20an%20unmanaged%20resource%2C%20such,makes%20them%20available%20for%20other%20code%20to%20use) and not have to explicitly call Dispose in the Finally.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you were using .Net Core or 4.x. If the later, you can sometimes use the Insert Snippet functionality to learn how to do common tasks. For example in this case you could right click in the code editor and select `Insert Snippet` then `Fundamentals` then `File System` and finally `Write text to a file`. This will result in the following VB code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Test.txt", "Text", True)
```

Unfortunately, this option doesn't work with .Net core since the My namespace wasn't ported to core.